# SQL expression error for Select Layer By Attribute

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, sql, select-by-attribute

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("N05-12_Station2_JGD.shp","station_12")

year=2012

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("station_12","#",'"closing">=%d AND "opening"<=%d' % year)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):File "", line 1, in
>   
>       arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("station_12","#",'"closing">=%d
>   AND "opening"<=%d' % year) TypeError: not enough arguments for format
>   string

I want to select records that closing>=2012 and opening<=2012.

Above script, it occurs an error.

How can I write right script?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is how you define the date. Dates in file geodatabases, shapefiles, and coverages are preceded with date. In [Esri Help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000033000000), you can find examples on usage.

> "Datefield" = date 'yyyy-mm-dd'

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
in_fc = r"C:\GIS\Temp\LayerB_shp.shp"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_fc,"station_12")
year="date '2012-01-01'"
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("station_12","#",""""closing">={0} AND "opening"<={0}""".format(year))
print int(arcpy.GetCount_management("station_12").getOutput(0))
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that substitution method has been deprecated, use format instead:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("station_12","#",'"x">={0} AND "y"<={0}'.format(year))
```

Answer (score 1):

The "TypeError: not enough arguments for format string" is caused by the var substitution expecting 2 params - the 'format' command will 'map' your substitutions by index in the tuple specified.  To write a similar query via the % operator, it is still supported using ArcGIS 10.2.x, however make sure you understand a string (%s) is being constructed (so you cannot use %d).  Consider this command comparison testing within IDLE:

```
>>> year="date '2012-01-01'"
>>> print year
date '2012-01-01'

>>> '"closing">={0} AND "opening"<={0}"'.format(year)
'"closing">=date \'2012-01-01\' AND "opening"<=date \'2012-01-01\'"'

>>> '"closing">=%d AND "opening"<=%d' % (year,year)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#15>", line 1, in <module>
    '"closing">=%d AND "opening"<=%d' % (year,year)
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str

>>> '"closing">=%s AND "opening"<=%s' % (year,year)
'"closing">=date \'2012-01-01\' AND "opening"<=date \'2012-01-01\''
>>>
```

Incidentally, in case you were wondering about the data type storage itself in the file gdb (10.2.x), then check this out - it's accessible via Python's datetime object:

```
>>> # using the da cursor to examine and modify datetime objs
>>> rows = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("testAliasName",['UpdateOn','EndDate'])
>>> row = rows.next()

>>> # the row listing returned of 2 date fields- these are null values
>>> print row
[datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 30, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 30, 0, 0)]

>>> # using a tuple to set date values
>>> row[0] = datetime.datetime(2011, 12, 1, 0, 0)
>>> row[1] = datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 1, 0, 0)
>>> rows.updateRow(row)
>>> del row, rows

>>> # now do the selection using your query format
>>> year = "date '2012-01-01'"
>>> print year
date '2012-01-01'

>>> # for convenience, setting up the query as a var
>>> query = '"EndDate" >= %s AND "UpdateOn" <= %s' % (year, year)
>>> print query
"EndDate" >= date '2012-01-01' AND "UpdateOn" <= date '2012-01-01'

>>> # the select by attribute using the formed query
>>> arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("testAliasName", "NEW_SELECTION", query)
<Result 'testAliasName'>
>>>  # works fine
```